# External monitors connected via Dell dock have no signal after booting

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-mate, dock

When I boot my Ubuntu Mate laptop with 2 external screens connected via a dock, the primary (laptop) screen works immediately, but the external screens are not functional. They show up in Displays but they are in standby and don't seem to get any signal.

Facts:

- I'm using a Dell Latitude E7450 laptop with NVidia GeForce 840, proprietary NVidia drivers, and the GPU set to Intel.
- Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS
- The laptop is on a Dell E-port dock, two Dell screens are connected to the dock (one via DisplayPort, one via DVI).
- The screens are detected by the OS, they show up in Displays, but the monitors remain in standby.
- if I disconnect the laptop from the dock and connect it again, the screens start working.
- if I boot the laptop away from the dock and then connect it, the screens also start working.
- I attempted to boot the laptop away from the dock, with one of the screens connected via mini-DisplayPort. The screen worked immediately after boot. This makes me think it might be connected to the dock.

Here's the output of:

- [`xrandr` output on the dock](https://pastebin.com/fPDy15KA) - same no matter if screens are working or not
- [`dmesg` after booting, screens not working](https://pastebin.com/TyN4eVkN)
- [`dmesg` continued](https://pastebin.com/HKBPWAqw) right after disconnecting and connecting the dock

Comment: Update: I'm using vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 nowadays and the problem is mostly gone here. I _sometimes_ get no input signal on one of the screens, it's pretty random and also goes away by disconnecting and re-connecting the laptop to the dock.